# Looking for high resolution (1m or better) aerials for Turkey?

Tags: data, wms, imagery, turkey

Would prefer free but under a couple hundred dollars is also doable.

It would be nice to have actual tif, sid, etc. files but a WMS would also work.

The WMS (bing and esri) I have been able to locate have holes and poor resolution in many areas of our 24k scale Turkey project.

[aerial problem areas here](http://v1.iimmgg.com/images/is11gr/ec8f0500354b6df13549b006f26fd962.png)

Have attempted to use the trial versions of ArcBruTile and Global Mapper. Both of which don't provide what we need without spending too much on what looks like overpriced convoluted products.

It seems there has to be some high resolution aerials for Turkey that are free/inexpensive and user friendly to download/use.

Comment: Global Mapper is not an overpriced product compared to other commercial software. It all depends on what you want to do with it. GeoEye has high quality imagery for Turkey at cost - http://www.geoeye.com/CorpSite/

Answer (score 2):

Digital Globe has a pretty good coverage of Turkey. (see below) This only includes existing archival imagery so if you see any holes in the coverage it means that DG has not collected any imagery there.  When you enable the DigitalGlobe coverage layer in Google Earth and zoom in you can click on the DG icons which will expose the caltalog ID and basic information about cloud cover and quality.  You can then order the existing archival imagery directly from Digital Globe.  The minimum order of any archival imagery from DG is 25km2. the cost depends on whether you want the image to be precisely orthorectified or not.  The 25km2 can be had for about $400.  Orthorectified is a few hundred more.

You can custom order any area on earth and the order starts at minimum 100km2. When I priced it out several years ago it was roughly $10,000 for a minimum custom order.  Also want to point out that in order to purchase imagery from DG dirrect our company had to be screened by the Homeland Security to whom we had to provide a lot detailed information about our company.  This processed might be more difficult depending where you are. It's been a few years since I have done this so I am not sure if these rules still apply.

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you have a high-resolution image like a screenshot directly embedded in your post, you might want to make a thumbnail version of it for quick viewing and then link to the full-resolution image so when someone clicks the thumbnail they are taken to the full image. At least for me on Firefox the downscaled screenshot is aliased and illegible, until I right-click and do "View Image".

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get free OrbView images from GeoEye catalog.

There are nice satellite imagens with spatial resolution 1 meter - just submit a KML file to search database: http://www.processamentodigital.com.br/?p=2455

Comment: unfortunately, OrbView from GeoEye via usgs was lacking coverage and was probably too old (2003) for this project, thanks for the free source though.